# How would I go about logging into Mojang using HTTP requests? (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, http

The website that I want to be able to log into is:
https://account.mojang.com/login

I want the fastest way to be able to send requests to Mojang's servers. So if using sockets would be faster than HTTP requests, then I'd like to know how to use sockets.

I've looked at tutorials here and there and I'm still confused as to how I would go about doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Because it sure sounds like you're trying to hack their server.

Comment: An http request is made over a tcp socket, so the question really does not make sense. Have to agree with the poster above too, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to interact with the website through Java. Once I log in, I'm can click another link then change my player's name. I'm trying to change my name programatically.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?